# Strategy for content aggregator service

Tags: php, mysql, linux, rss, aggregator

I have built RSS, twitter, and other content aggregators for clients using php/Mysql. It typically involves a cron job, some feed parsing and inserting data into a database for storing and later re-publishing, or deleting, or archiving, etc. Nothing ground-breaking.

But now I am tasked with building an aggregator service for a public audience. I imagine this will need to scale quickly as each person with access to the service can add dozens, if not hundred of source feeds. Within a few months we may be regularly parsing 1000's of feeds and maybe 100,000 within a year, or more with any luck.

I guess the ultimate model is something similar to what google reader does.

So, what is a good strategy for this? Multiple, overlapping crons, continuously running and reading feeds and connecting to APIs to pull content? Should I plan to run multiple instances of Elastic Cloud or something as need grows?

Comment: explain 'queues'? I am not familiar.

Comment: it is a sort of software. RabbitMQ is one of queue managers for example

Comment: intrigued by RabbitMQ. So it looks like I set that up on a dedicated server, have it buffer all of my update requests in a queue and then I can audit the queue and if it gets too long I can set up another instance a round robin the requests sent?

Comment: somebody post 'queues' as the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever timed how long it takes to parse one feed? Depending on how often you check for feed updates, even 100,000 feeds does not strike me as too much. Are you sure a more complicated system is necessary? If it is, you could consider a simpler solution, such as limiting one server to a set number of feeds, and throwing more hardware at it as your feeds increase. Amazon would be great for this I think.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like OP was satisfied by queues (it would be good if you update your question with your final solution)

Answer (score 0):

I would not overlap crons, will get really nasty at the end. I guess you should have one system that sends information with Ajax and multiple servers accepting and rendering it, returning action and results if needed.
On the other hand, there are many cloud solutions available worldwide, might work even better.